# python setup.py install not working in Windows due to admin?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, admin

I tried to run `python setup.py install` in Windows cmd, but got this error. In MAC I just change to `sudo python setup.py install`, but in Windows not suod. I tried `runas` also not working. I also tried `python setup.py install --user` the installation didn't report error but the function did not work.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

```
    C:\Users\ccc\Desktop\pyrbdome-master>python setup.py install
Python development and setuptools have been installed...
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-2820.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Comment: Using the `--user` option should install it for the local user. I would also suggest looking into using virtual environments when installing python packages

Comment: Do I need to install a vritual environments to my PC? Does it mean python have some compatiable issues with PC or only this package?

Comment: Virtual environments just allow isolation of installed packages for a given project so that you don't clutter your main python installation, and it allows you to have different versions of a package installed in each environment. It is probably not required here, but is one possible solution to your issue. I would suggest taking a look at the built-in [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module to start

Comment: Thanks! It's difficult for me but at least now I now where to start with!

Comment: Like always in Windows, Right Click - Run As Administrator.

Comment: @LiangcuiChu did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @HattrickNZ Hi sorry just see your comments. The problems is the package I need to install requires Linux enviroment. So I have to run it by Ubuntu or Linux server. Windonws dose not work in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is the package I need to install requires Linux enviroment. So I have to run it by Ubuntu or Linux server. Windonws dose not work in any way. Hope can help!